# Use CONTAINS or ANY in CloudKit predicate with an array of comparison

Tags: ios, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery

I tried to use `NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates:)` with `CloudKit` `NSPredicate` but then I read on Apple's documentation that `OR` comparison predicates aren't supported in `CloudKit` so I hit a road-block with this.

I have an array of `CKReferences` that I need to see if a `Record-type` of `Reference list` contains those references.

I'm struggling on how to assemble the predicate itself , because I'm trying to avoid nested-queries in the `completionBlock`.

let's say I have the following array of references:

```
let refs = [CKReference]() // in my case the array isn't empty
```

I tried the following but it didn't worked, because somehow it only looks for the first object of the array, and not the whole array.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "tableName CONTAINS %@", argumentArray: refs)
```

Here if I print the `predicate` it prints:

> tableName CONTAINS CKReference: 0x600000229c40; 20B54862-46CC-405F-BAE8-0DC8D3A52F78:(_defaultZone:**defaultOwner**)>

As you can see, it only looks for the first object in the array.

It may work if I use the `ANY` operator in the predicate, something like:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY { '%@', '%@' } = tableName", args: refs[0], refs[1])
```

But my problem here is how can I build that predicate, since the `refs` array is dynamic and I don't know how many objects it may contain , and by that I don't know how to build the `predicate args` accessing the `[0], [1], ...` of the `refs` array.

Do you have any workaround with this? Or a best way to approach this issue?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I figure out a way to solve this issue, but I don't know if that's the most efficient one, so I'm still opened to answers and opinions.

Here's my temporary solution:

```
for (i, reference) in  refs.enumerated() {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "tableName CONTAINS %@", reference)
    // CKQuery
    // CKQueryOperation
    // Database.add(CKQueryOperation)
    if i == refs.count - 1 {
        // UPDATE UI
    }
}
```

Comment: `"tableName IN %@", refs`?

Comment: @Larme since reference is a REFERENCE_LIST type, it cannot be queried using filter type IN.

Comment: To be clear, your `tableName` represents a list of CKReference and you want to create a predicate using another list of CKReference to see if there is a non-empty intersection of the two arrays. Is that correct?

Comment: @rmaddy exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray * tagsReferencesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [tagsReferencesArray addObject:tag100_Reference];
    [tagsReferencesArray addObject:tag300_Reference];
    [tagsReferencesArray addObject:tag200_Reference];

predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %@ in field_TagsReferenceList ", tagsReferencesArray];
```